# Find dimension of $V$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ denote vector space $C^{5} [a,b]$ over $\Bbb R$ and

$$W=\left \{f\in V: \frac{\mathrm d^{4}f}{\mathrm dt^{4}}+2\frac{\mathrm d^{2}f}{\mathrm dt^{2}} - f =0\right \}$$

What are the dimensions of $V$ and $W$?

Comment: The first one is very easy, for the second try to make the ansatz $f(t)=ae^{\lambda t}$, which values for $\lambda$ are possible?

Comment: Thnx all of u 4 ur valuable time and support. @Fakesupport ur explanation is too good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$ \dim V= \infty$$

and

$$ \dim W= 4.$$

Comment: Let's hope he understands it

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is infinite dimensional, you can easily see that every polynomial, or exponential function, sine function, etc. are elements of $V$. $W$ however, is a smaller space. The elements can be found by simply solving the ODE. Since no boundary/intial values are given, these will be the valid solutions up to some constants, the ODE should tell you how many.